# How to force not delete stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-kinesis, serverless

I deployed a CloudFormation Kinesis stream.

Then I made a new deploy from another stream with another name... the previous one was deleted. That is, it deletes the previous one and always keeps the last deploy.

I did not find in the documentation anything that explains how to force deploy not to delete the Kinesis created stream.

Any idea?

Follow my Kinesis resource config, on serverless.yml

```
resources:
  Resources:
    KinesisStream:
      Type: AWS::Kinesis::Stream
      Properties:
        Name: kinesis_name_1
        ShardCount: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `Name` property replaces your Kinesis stream. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-kinesis-stream.html#cfn-kinesis-stream-name):

> Name: ...
>
> Update requires: Replacement

If you modify the `Name` property of your `AWS::Kinesis::Stream` resource, a *new* Kinesis stream will be created with the new name, and the Kinesis stream with the old name will be deleted.